# Ionic 2 Tabs reset view when clicking another tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

Wondering how I can do this. When using ionic tabs, lets say I have a simple structure like

```
Home
About
Product -> Product Info
```

In my Products page (product.ts) I have something like

```
viewItem(payload) {
this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage, {
  data: payload
});
}
// ^ Pass data to new Product info page.
```

The product info page loads fine all data passes in and I get a back arrow in the nav bar.

Now if I click another tab like About and go back to Product it still shows the pushed Product Info page.

How can I get it to reset back to the Product page when I leave the view and navigate back?

Update:

If I do this

```
ionViewDidLeave() {
this.viewCtrl.dismiss().catch(() => console.log('Some bug going on..'));
}
```

Works, but have to catch the error otherwise returns

```
Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): false
```

Looks like its a bug  - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/10046

If anyone has any other suggestion its much appreciated.

Comment: can you show the code of `tabs.ts` and `tabs.html` page also?

Comment: @Sampath - Yeah not alot goes on in tab.ts, similar to here - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs/blob/master/src/pages/tabs/tabs.ts Its when pushing a page, you get the back button, however navigating to another tab and the back it still shows the pushed page. With my App I need it to reset to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

`NavController` comes with events. One of them is `ionViewDidLeave`.

In that you can `pop` the page you don't want to be kept stacked.

```
ionViewDidLeave() {
   this.navCtrl.pop();
}
```

Comment: I get a promise error with this.  Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): false

Comment: Try perhaps `ionViewWillLeave` check the full list [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)

Comment: @Erevald   i have one problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716187/ionic-2-back-button-or-any-icon-is-not-showing-only-small-box-icon-is-showing